# How to have a ListView without scrolling the parent column view in flutter?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

Please look at this image [Home Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qhH0h.png)

Now when I scroll the ListView it becomes like this -
[Home Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1zcD6.png)

Now I know the reason why this is happening, it is because I used ListView as a parent to this entire view and added ListView.builder() and other widgets as its child.

What I want is to scroll the ListView.builder() without scrolling the entire page.

For this I first tried to use Column as parent but that ended up giving the overflow pixels error.
And then I set the physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics() inside the parent ListView but after that it made my ListView.builder() to show all of its list items.

Here is my Code for Home Screen

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
  body: Column(
    children: [
      Expanded(
        child: ListView(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 45, bottom: 24),
          children: [
            header(),
            const SizedBox(height: 36),
            const BalanceCard(),
            const SizedBox(height: 36),
            Recent()
          ],
        ),
      ),
      Align(
        alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
        child: bottomNavigationBar(),
      ),
    ],
  ),
); }
```

Recent List Code

```
class RecentItems extends StatefulWidget {
final List<Transaction> transactions;

RecentItems({required this.transactions});

@override
State<RecentItems> createState() => _RecentItemsState();
}
class _RecentItemsState extends State<RecentItems> {
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return SizedBox(
    height: 450,
    child: Expanded(child: ListView.builder(
           itemBuilder: (context, index) {
      final item = widget.transactions[index].toString();
      return Dismissible(
        direction: DismissDirection.endToStart,
        key: UniqueKey(),
        onDismissed: (direction) {
          setState(() {
            widget.transactions.removeAt(index);
          });

          // Then show a snackbar.
          ScaffoldMessenger.of(context)
              .showSnackBar(const SnackBar(content: Text('Transaction Deleted')));
        },
        background: Container(
          color: Colors.red,
          alignment: AlignmentDirectional.centerEnd,
          child: const Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0.0, 0.0, 15.0, 0.0),
            child: Icon(
              EvaIcons.trash2,
              color: Colors.white,
            ),
          ),
        ),

        child: Card(
          elevation: 5,
          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
          ),
          child: ListTile(
            leading: CircleAvatar(
              radius: 30,
              foregroundImage: widget.transactions[index].Image,
              backgroundColor: primaryColor,
            ),
            title: Text(
              widget.transactions[index].title,
              style: const TextStyle(color: secondaryColor),
            ),
            subtitle: Text(
              DateFormat.yMMMd().format(widget.transactions[index].date),
            ),
            trailing: Text(
              '\$${widget.transactions[index].amount}',
              style: const TextStyle(color: secondaryColor),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      );
    },
    itemCount: widget.transactions.length,
  ),)
);
}
}
```

Recent Widget -

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Padding(
  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 24),
  child: Column(
    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
    children: [
      const Text(
        'Recent Transactions',
        style: TextStyle(
            fontSize: 15,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
            color: secondaryColor),
      ),
      const SizedBox(height: 5),
      RecentItems(transactions: _userTransactions),
    ],
  ),
)
```

Comment: Do you want only the `Recent()` widget to be scrollable, and the rest of the widgets fixed?

Comment: Yes I want only Recent() to be scrollable

Comment: Try to wrap only `Recent` into `Expanded`, remove the other `Expanded` and `ListView`, put everything into a `Column` and only `Recent` into `Expanded`.

Comment: That is giving pixel overflowed error and unable to scroll complete list

Comment: And if you set column's `mainAxisSize` to max?

Comment: It still gives overflow error

Comment: I will add a skeleton example in an answer shortly.

Answer (score 0):

The entire screen scrolls because `Recent()` is included in the same ListView as `header()` and `balanceCard()`.

Try something like this:

```
Scaffold(
        body: Column(
          children: [
            Expanded(
              child: ListView(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 45, bottom: 24),
                children: [
                  header(),
                  const SizedBox(height: 36),
                  const BalanceCard(),
                  const SizedBox(height: 36),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            // Recent items removed from ListView
            Recent(),
            Align(
              alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
              child: bottomNavigationBar(),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      )
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: That made my balanceCard() disappear.

Comment: Have you tried wrapping Recent() in an Expanded widget? Even adding the flex property within the Expanded widget may help with spacing (Expanded's default flex value is 1.)

Comment: Yes, I did. It didn't worked.

Comment: I am not at a PC now, but try to remove the Expanded from the header()/balanceCard() section and add it to the Recent() part. It will then let Recent() occupy the available space.

Answer (score 0):

By simplifying your code, this is an example of a layout where you have a single `Column` in the `Scaffold`. The `Column` contains some sized, unsized and aligned children.

One child, `Recent` is a `ListView`, without explicit height, but wrapped into an `Expanded` widget. This way it will occupy all the remaining area left by the other children, and it will be scrollable.

(You will run into trouble with this if the children without `Recent` occupy all the available area.)

Please have a look at this code, you can copy-paste it into a DartPad fiddle:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: MyWidget(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => Scaffold(
        body: Column(
          children: [
            const Text('header()'),
            const SizedBox(height: 36),
            const Text('BalanceCard()'),
            const SizedBox(height: 36),
            Expanded(child: Recent()),
            const Align(
              alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
              child: Text('bottomNavigationBar()'),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      );
}

class Recent extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => ListView.builder(
      itemCount: 100, itemBuilder: (context, index) => Text('Item $index'));
}
```

Comment: This is giving me PIXEL OVERFLOWED ERROR

Comment: You should not specify an explicit height for `Recents`. I think the remaining height is simply not enough.

Comment: If I’m not specifying the height then the entire screen is blank.